# Как использовать данные Фамилия Имя Отчество в проверке данных с диапозоном вывода, в случае возможного их изменения в будущем?

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet, таблицы, excel-формулы

**Цель:** привязывать к ФИО определённые данные/транзакции в таблице. Использовать список ФИО, с помощью проверки данных, с возможностью выбора заполняющему. Заполняющему ориентироваться на уникальный номер не представляется возможным, и не удобно, гораздо практичнее ориентироваться по ФИО. Уникальный номер присваивается уже после выбранного ФИО.

Как использовать данные Фамилия Имя Отчество в проверке данных с диапозоном вывода, **в случае возможного их изменения в будущем?** (исправление опечаток/изменение фамилии).

В данный момент происходит следующим образом:

На странице с ФИО, имеются список ФИО и уникальный НОМЕР для каждого ФИО.

**Страница с ФИО**

|  | A № | B ФИО |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | Тестов Тест Тестович |
| 2 | 002 | Пупкин Василий Иванович |

На странице с транзакциями присваивается уникальный номер, в зависимости от выбранной ФИО в выпадающем списке, организованном с помощью проверки данных и выводом диапазона ФИО со страницы "Страница с ФИО".
Формула:

```
=FILTER('Страница с ФИО'!A:A, 'Страница с ФИО'!B:B=B1)
```

**Страница с транзакциями**

|  | A № | B ФИО | C Транзакция |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | Тестов Тест Тестович | +100 |
| 2 | 002 | Пупкин Василий Иванович | +1000 |
| 3 | 001 | Тестов Тест Тестович | -10 |
| 4 | 001 | Тестов Тест Тестович | -20 |
| 5 | 002 | Пупкин Василий Иванович | -10 |
| 6 | 001 | Тестов Тест Тестович | -10 |

И всё бы ничего, всё работает, подсчёт совершенных транзакций ведётся по уникальному номеру.
Однако, когда Я вношу изменения в ФИО, формула, указанная выше перестаёт работать, так как введённое значение, уже не существует.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как всё-таки правильно создавать базу данных на Google Sheets?

Создал для эксперементов таблицу, по ссылке:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xzWz_Qm_zg4zRohfWcF1pzXBiIs6qU1_H0k5wIH2dDM/edit?usp=sharing

С 9ой строки можно эксперементировать

Comment: Ну так вы в таблице с транзакциями пишите не имя а ссылку на ячейку с именем вот и все

Comment: В чем проблема? Если правильно настроена проверка данных, то заполняющий не сможет вписать что-либо "левое". Перечень ФИО в отдельном справочнике, в проверке данных - ссылка на этот диапазон.

Comment: И не путайте Excel и Google-таблицы. Да, похожи, но - РАЗНЫЕ, и решения могут отличаться.

Comment: @SelfishCrawler как если заполняющий выбирает из диапозона имён, а не вписывает в ручную. В таком случае заполняющий просто вводил бы уникальный номер, присвоенный к ФИО.

Comment: @vikttur Я в курсе, но может кто-то подскажет решение в Excel, а там уже по аналогии перенесу в Google Sheets.

Comment: @vikttur проблема возникает тогда, когда данные выбраны из диапозона, а затем меняются данные и выдаётся ошибка #N/A "В результате выполнения функции FILTER ничего не обнаружено"

Comment: добавил скриншот для ясности

Comment: Создал для экссперементов таблицу. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xzWz_Qm_zg4zRohfWcF1pzXBiIs6qU1_H0k5wIH2dDM/edit?usp=sharing Со строками 11 и дальше можно эксперементировать

Comment: Работать с таблицами надо не так, как хочется, а по правилам, приемлемым для таблиц. В Вашем случае возможен только скрипт-костыль, который будет подставлять константой ID при выборе ФИО

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118420/discussion-between-goldenscrew-and-vikttur).

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю задачу, я бы переделал flow по-принципу:

1. Страница с ФИО, туда вносим контрагентов
2. На странице с транзакциями подтягиваем ФИО через валидацию с первой страницы. С запретом ввода неправильных значений.

Comment: А потом в таблице (или на странице с ФИО) исправят *Тестович*а на *ТестовичЧ*а (а именно в этом проблема)...  Все, старые записи не определяются )

Comment: Ок, тогда используем для идентификации именно код клиента. А ФИО подтягиваем через Filter или VLOOKUP.

Comment: Можно еще сильнее заморочиться и через макрос (Appscript) сделать форму ввода, где выбираться будет по ФИО, а запись создаваться по ID

Comment: О еще вариант — запретить менять имеющиеся ФИО, но если допустим нужно внести изменения, то под тем же ID добавить еще одно ФИО. Его можно будет выбрать в списке. А для аналитики использовать уникальные ID клиентов.

Comment: >> *под тем же ID добавить еще одно ФИО* - и в списке будут и старые ФИО, и новые... А пользователю может быть до лампочки, какое значение выбирать.

Comment: А какая разница с точки зрения аналитики? Пользователь выберет, то, что ему сейчас нужно. Была Зайцева, сменила фамилию стала Волкова. Пользователю, который регистрирует продажу нужно ввести Волкову в базу и на странице транзакций выбрать Волкову.

Может есть вопрос, на который надо дать сначала ответ: "Что вы вообще пытаетесь получить?"

Comment: >> _запретить менять имеющиеся ФИО, но если допустим нужно внести изменения, то под тем же ID добавить еще одно ФИО. Его можно будет выбрать в списке. А для аналитики использовать уникальные ID клиентов_ @Oleksandr  спасибо! Похоже то, что нужно!!! Только, не желательно предлагать выбор старых данных, хоть аналитика и будет по айди. И как запретить изменение предыдущих транзакций, в идеале, чтобы не пересчитывало эти айди через =FILTER, так как подгружает очень серъёзно таблицу. Можно как-то в правила проверки данных написать формулу, чтобы выводило соответствующее значение с поледним номером?

Comment: >> *исправлять не в таблице, куда вносятся данные, а* **ТОЛЬКО в списке-источнике проверки данных.** - неужели это не ответ на Ваш вопрос? НЕ множить  фамилии с одним ID, а МЕНЯТЬ ФИО при одном ID, иначе вся уникальность летит к чертям...

Comment: @vikttur при изменении ФИО на **Странице с ФИО**, старые записи на **Странице с транзакциями** приходят в негодность. Все ID будут затёрты, данные придётся перезаписывать с уже изменённой фамилией, чтобы получать ID.

Comment: О курочке и яйцах я Вам написал в комментарии к своему ответу. Нельзя одной ногой стоять на берегу, другой на льдине - риск заработать растяжение  и искупаться в холодной воде ) Везде существуют какие-то ограничения и Вы  должны это учитывать. А "по щучьему велению" - это в сказках....

Comment: Для того чтобы выбирать можно было из только последних значений под ID на странице с ФИО кидаем в какую-то ячейку формулу: =arrayformula(iferror(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE($A$2:$A),sort($A$2:$B,ARRAYFORMULA(row($A$2:$A)),0),2,false))) и уже оттуда забираем возможные значения в валидатор.

Answer (score 0):

Учитесь работать с данными не так, как вздумается, а по каким-то правилам.

*Иванова* работала лет 5, вышла замуж, стала *Бабаягова*. Нормально? Вполне. Но как в Вашей таблице определить, например, стаж работы прелестной девушки *Прекрасная* (ну, не понравилась фамилия, поменяли через 3 года)?

Не ищите проблем на свою голову.

Простое решение: исправлять не в таблице, куда вносятся данные, а **ТОЛЬКО в списке-источнике проверки данных**.

Исправили, зашли в таблицу и заменили предыдущее ФИО на исправленное (вручную, макросом - неважно). Если нужно хранить данные об изменениях ФИО - хранить в отдельной таблице. Не нужно мух сажать на котлеты )

А наличие в рабочей базе разних имен для одного человека - это наличие (сейчас или в будущем) головной боли при работе с такими данными.

---

Но если трудности - это Ваше все :), ждите, кто переведет макрос, написанный на `VBA` для `Excel`
, на родной для `Google`-таблиц `JS`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B:B"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Target.Row < 2 Then Exit Sub
        
        With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .EnableEvents = False: End With

        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, Worksheets("list").Range("A2:B100"), 2, 0)
        End If

        With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .EnableEvents = True: End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Добавлять или изменять ФИО нужно только на листе, где расположен список.

При изменении в рабочей таблице в столбце В в столбец А записывается номер, соответствующий ФИО. Если изменить ранее созданную запись, будет изменен и номер.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После изменения в списке в рабочую таблицу при выборе ФИО будут подтягиваться новые данные, при этом записи в ранее заполненных строках не изменятся (если в них не менять ФИО).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Заменять на страницах после изменений это понятно, что можно, но это не верно, хочется то не прибегать к действиям замены. Правда не совсем понял до конца, что Вы имели ввиду, завтра ещё вникну. А вообще, как по Вашему лучше вести учёт всех транзакций на уникальное лицо? Как дать уникальное значение, к которой всё присваивать, номер нормально? Может возможно присваивать уникальный номер в транзакциях единоразово, чтобы номер не переписывался в дальнейшем даже при изменении ФИО (НЕ команду =FILTER)? Наверня-ка как-то же ведут учет в таблицах, изменяя начальные значения...

Comment: >> *чтобы номер не переписывался в дальнейшем даже при изменении ФИО* - это вообще глупость...  Вместо Иванова случайно записали Петрова. Хороший вариант, да? Вы как специально ищете проблемы для себя.

Comment: Вы правы. Но Ваш вариант с макросами не хочу использовать, думаю можно обойтись как-то более просто.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы и курочка каждый день неслась, и наваристого бульончика искушать :)

Comment: да, и вариант Oleksandr Maksymeniuk прост в исполнении и впринципе подходит, осталось лишь немного его доработать.

Comment: Да, совсем немного... Но *запретить менять имеющиеся ФИО* без скриптов?  И как быть, когда у пользователя будет возможность выбирать из списка  2-4 ФИО для одного ID? Удачи в решении...